# Trying to install EE on MAC localhost - getting error in Licence.php

Tags: install, localhost

I'm trying to install EE 3.2.1 on localhost on my Mac. But I'm getting the following 'undefined function' error. Through Google I can't find any mention of anyone else having the same issue. What might be the cause?

```
Call to undefined function EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\License\openssl_verify()
in /Users/xxxxx/www/iffa/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/License/License.php on line 248
```

My system versions are:
Apache: 5.5.31
mySQL:  5.6.25

Answer (score 3):

`openssl_verify` is a PHP function, so you need to install it for PHP, normally it's installed as standard, so guess you're using an abnormal PHP installer...?

Here's a [reference to a bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21556/after-installation-of-licensed-copy-of-ee-log-in-attempt-displays-openssl_v) that was created.

It may be as simple as you've not got the php.ini module line uncommented:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

PHP OpenSSL [Installation reference](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php).

Comment: Thanks Peter,
I was able to install the openssl extension and all is good now.